# How to loop through string, adding 1 extra character to an array each time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use JS to loop through a string value while adding the first character and the following characters to an array. This process repeats again with the next character.

For example, if I were to input ABCD then the array would turn out to be:

[A, AB, ABC, ABCD, B, BC, BCD, C, CD, D]

Comment: Can you please share your attempts so that we can steer you in the right direction?

Comment: Hello, It appears you are new to the community.  Please take the time to read through this post to learn how to best ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `[].concat(...'ABCD'.replace(/(.)/g, \`$1$'\n\`).split\`\n\`.map(s=> s.replace(/(.)/g, '$\`$1\n').split\`\n\`)).filter(x => x)`

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```js
var str = 'ABCD'
var arr = []
for (var j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
 for (var i = 0; i < str.length - j; i++) {
   arr.push(str.substr(j, i+1))
 }
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can split your problem into two small function first function `combination of a single word` then pass this function for every element in a `single world` an play with the `substring` params.

```js
const text = "ABCD";
const arrayOfCombination = [];

const combinationWord = word => [...word].map((el, index) => word.substring(0, index + 1));

[...text].forEach((el, index) => arrayOfCombination.push(combinationWord(text.substring(index, text.length))));

console.log(arrayOfCombination.flat())
```